# Unable to override property in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is there anyway to override spring boot property of parent context in child context?

I had tried various options:

1) Both parent & child in respective XML: property-placeholder ordering similar to non boot project (child order > parent order) : **Not working**

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:parent-config.properties" order="-10"
        ignore-unresolvable="true" ignore-resource-not-found="true" />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:child-config.properties" order="-5"
        ignore-unresolvable="true" ignore-resource-not-found="true" />
```

2) Both parent & child in respective Java @Configuration : **Not working**

```
@PropertySource(value={"classpath:parent-config.properties"}, ignoreResourceNotFound=true)
@PropertySource(value={"classpath:child-config.properties"})
```

3) Parent in XML property-placeholder & child in Java `@Configuration` : **Works some times, not Always**

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:parent-config.properties" order="-10"
            ignore-unresolvable="true" ignore-resource-not-found="true" />
 @PropertySource(value={"classpath:child-config.properties"})
```

4) Both parent & child in `@PropertySource` of `@Configuration` in order: **Working**

```
@PropertySource(value={"classpath:parent-config.properties", "classpath:child-config.properties"})
```

As I am importing/extending parent context which already have "classpath:parent-config.properties", I should not be mentioning the parent config again in child.
Is there any proper solution for the same??

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot automatically load application.properties from classpath (src/main/resources, if you are using Maven).

Take look at [Externalized Configuration chapter of Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config).

Answer (score 0):

If the same property exists in both parent-config.properties and child-config.properties, then last @PropertySource annotation will "win" and override the value. See the last section here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html

In this case, #4 works because you're specifying both properties file in the same annotation and the child-config.properties is being processed later.

Others might work or not work depending on which order these properties files were detected. Since @PropertySource annotations are auto-scanned, it's hard to control the order.

Your options are:

1. ensure that a property exists only in the parent or child config.properties
2. use the programmatic PropertySource API (MutablePropertySources addFirst / addLast methods)

here's a sample example I found - http://scottfrederick.cfapps.io/blog/2012/05/30/Custom-PropertySource-in-Spring-3.1---Part-3

also, documentation for MutablePropertySources - http://cloud-vm45.cloud.cnaf.infn.it:8085/webdav/noauth/spring-framework-3.2.8.RELEASE/docs/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/MutablePropertySources.html